# AngularFire: run method when $firebaseArray changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have the following setup:

```
var x = $firebaseArray(ref);
x.$loaded().then(function () {

    self.y = //I change y based on x

}
```

Per the documentation `$loaded` only runs once but I need to change `self.y` each time `x` updates. I know I can extend `$firebaseArray` but in my case that is not an option because `self.y` is also dependable on another `$firebaseArray`.

**So my question is:** Is there a way to run a method each time `$firebaseArray` updates of even in general **in JavaScript is there a way to watch a variable for change and run a method each time it does.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform some operation on the data whenever it changes, `$loaded()` is the wrong approach. Instead, you'll want to [extend `$firebaseArray`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html#section-firebasearray) and override the `$$added`, `$$changed`... methods. See [this fiddle for an example of extending a `$firebaseObject`](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/syuzw9k1/), which is similar.

But if you're not binding the `$firebaseArray()` to the scope, you might as well use the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK and use an `on('value'`:

```
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    self.y = // change y based on snapshot.val()
});
```

AngularFire is a great library for binding Firebase data to AngularJS views. It is not a replacement for the Firebase JavaScript SDK. In fact, it is built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK and the two interoperate perfectly. So use AngularFire for binding data to views (and extend `$firebaseArray` if you need to customize the data), *but* use the Firebase JavaScript SDK for data that is not bound to a view.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AngularJS then you can use `$watch`.
[Read More Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

In your case you can do

```
  $scope.$watch('$firebaseArray', function(newV, oldV) {
         // Run whatever method you want
      }, true);
```

Comment: Yes but unless I am missing something that only works for scope variables. in this case x is a local variable.

Comment: Watch is not needed with AngularFire as you can receive updates from the server and act on those changes.